# How can I display and format HTML code within the page?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to display html code just like what your see here.

```
<textarea><script id="ff">gdgdgs</script></textarea>
```

and have it displayed without altering the page. and have it nicely within a box like this.

How is this achieved?

Comment: Don't forget to mark one of them as the answer! (the green tick) :)

Comment: thanks, this is my first post and I love this place already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
&lt;textarea&gt;&lt;script id=&quot;ff&quot;&gt;gdgdgs&lt;/script&gt;&lt;/textarea&gt;
```

Look up HTML entities.

Comment: you know that is just what I wanted. <?php echo htmlentities($_POST['test']);?> it puts the code in html, and doesn't allow it to alter the page, thankyou for that.

Comment: after I looked I saw this highlight_string($_POST['test']); to post it in color format, really is good.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is to actually have a look and see how Stackoverflow does it! :)

If you right click on your code box in Chrome and select inspect element, it'll show you the markup for that box. It's so useful to be able to do this, obviously not to rip people off, but learn how other people put websites together, and how they achieve cool effects like code boxes! :)

Interestingly enough though, if you simply right click on the page and go to *view source*, you'll see something slightly different:

```
<pre><code>&lt;textarea&gt;&lt;script id="ff"&gt;gdgdgs&lt;/script&gt;&lt;/textarea&gt;
</code></pre>
```

So we can see here that this is what the mark-up for that box looks like before the page has loaded and any JavaScript is run. When the page starts to load on the client side, some JavaScript will be run which takes the above mark-up and tranforms it to look like the mark up you see when you right click on the code box and inspect it in chrome. Doing this gives you a real-time view of the HTML on the page:

```
<pre class="lang-php prettyprint">
    <code>
        <span class="tag">&lt;textarea&gt;&lt;script</span>
        <span class="pln"></span>
        <span class="atn">id</span>
        <span class="pun">=</span>
        <span class="atv">"ff"</span>
        <span class="tag">></span>
        <span class="pln">gdgdgs</span>
        <span class="tag">&lt;/script&gt;&lt;/textarea&gt;</span>
        <span class="pln"><br></span>
    </code>
</pre>
```

So if you have a look, you can see the transformed code uses a *[pre](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/pre)* tag. This basically says, anything between here you can treat as a literal or in otherwords, keep line breaks and spaces where I left them!

As well as using the *[pre](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/pre)* tag to wrap the code, you can also see that they use different CSS classes. This is to achieve the color coding you can see.

They also use a *[code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/code)* tag which as far as I can see, is very similar to pre, only it makes your markup a bit clearer by saying, within this tag, you should expect to see code. It's probably more semantic more than anything, like the HTML tag *artical*. In most browsers, it'll also change the font for text inside the code tag to mono-space, which is a bit more code like! :)

You can go furhter into this and see exactly what their CSS classes look like, from this you can start to build a mental picture to see how their mark-up and CSS works together to product their nice code boxes.

Of course, if you don't want to roll this functionality yourself, you can use someone elses framework to achive this. [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) for example if widely used and recommended.

With Syntax Highlighter, you simply reference the Syntax Highlighter CSS and javascript, and then only need to wrap your code in one pre tag to get it working, something like below:

```
<pre class="brush: xml">
     &lt;textarea&gt;&lt;script id="ff"&gt;gdgdgs&lt;/script&gt;&lt;/textarea&gt;
</pre>
```

It might be worth a look!

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

you could use

```
&gt;
```

>

and

```
&lt;
```

<

Comment: yea thats what I mean, like in dreamweaver it converts code into html code.

Answer (score 1):

This website [here](http://www.addressmunger.com/display_code/) can help you with your particular problem. It converts your tags/html/javascript to ASCII. If you need a function, here it is. It converts the passed tags/html/javascript to ASCII. The ASCII code is escaped and treated as text by the browser. You can latter use the generated ASCII and add it to the box.

```
function stringToAscii(s)
{
  var ascii="";
  if(s.length>0)
    for(i=0; i<s.length; i++)
    {
      var c = ""+s.charCodeAt(i);
      while(c.length < 3)
       c = "0"+c;
      ascii += c;
    }
  return(ascii);
}
```

Comment: this worked perfectly for me even adding code it applied it to the page without destroying the layout, the only concern is the amount of extra bytes it takes up 5x chr for ever chr. this is what I finally used.
  
  function test2(s){
  var a = '';
  if(s.length>0){
   for(i=0; i<s.length; i++){
    var c = ""+s.charCodeAt(i);
    a+="&#"+c+";";
   }
  }
  document.getElementById("c").innerText='Test2: '+a;
 }

Answer (score 1):

Use the Encoded Version like this:

```
&lt;textarea&gt;
    &lt;script id="ff"&gt;
        gdgdgs
    &lt;/script&gt;
&lt;/textarea&gt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, just include it like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var a = '<textarea><script id="ff">gdgdgs</scrip'+'t></textarea>';
  $("div").css('background','red').text(a);
});
```

Comment: I don't understand that? how would I execute it and display it?

Comment: Well, you want to display the text as it is, right? Problem is that if you include it within HTML normally, the browser will read it as if you are declaring a normal script. So the only way to display it is either by using HTML entities as jussi stated above, or building the text dynamically and displaying it. Note that you can't say **var a = '<textarea><script id="ff">gdgdgs</script></textarea>';**, any mention of an opening **script** tag, followed by a closing one, will be interpreted by the browser as a script, eve if you are including it within quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [`<xmp>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/xmp) element.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/xmp It's deprecated though so probably not a good idea to use it!